# how shell script merging three files by lines and calculating some value, meeting some condition

Tags: shell, awk

```
while read line1
do
    while read line2
    do
        while read line3 
        do  echo "$line1, $line2, $line3" | awk -F , ' $1==$5 && $6==$11 && $10==$12 {print $1,",",$2,",",$3,",",$4,",",$6,",",$7,",",$8,",",$9,",",$10,",",$13,",",$14,",",$15}' >>out.txt
    done < grades.csv
    done < subjects.csv
done < students.csv
```

In this code i am merging three files by line(cross product) and if any merged line meets the condition "$1==$5 && $6==$11 && $10==$12", I am printing them in the output file.
Now my problem is i want to keep adding "$13" field values for each iteration if it meets the condition.

How can I do this? Please help. 
Here is the sample files.

**gardes.csv containes lines :**

```
1,ARCH,1,90,very good,80   
1,ARCH,2,70,good,85    
1,PLNG,1,89,very good,85
```

**subjects.csv contains lines :**

```
1,ARCH,Computer Architecture,A,K.Gose   
1,PLNG,Programming Languages,A,P.Yang    
1,OS,Operating System,B,K.Gopalan    
2,ARCH,Computer Architecture,A,K.Gose
```

**students.csv contains lines:**

```
1,pankaj,vestal,986-654-32   
2,satadisha,binghamton,879-876-54    
5,pankaj,vestal,986-654-32    
6,pankaj,vestal,986-654-31
```

This is the expected output:

```
ARCH  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  1  90  very good  80
ARCH  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  2  70  good       85
ARCH  2  satadisha  binghamton  879-876-54  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  1  90  very good  80
ARCH  2  satadisha  binghamton  879-876-54  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  2  70  good       85
PLNG  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Programming Languages  A  P.Yang  1  1  89  very good  85
```

Also I need the sum of (90+70+90+70+89) in another shell variable which can be written to a file.

Comment: better provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ fedorqui and @ Ryan hope this added full code and input files will help you to help me. thanks

Comment: csv files are dangerous. The code will break when you have a field with a `,`. How about the `7,ARCH,1,90,"very, very good",80`  or student `5,Louis,"Paris, France",986-654-32`?

Comment: @Walter, true, but in my requirement, I will have the fields without comma in it. comma will only be the separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join` to create your expanded data and operate with `awk` on it.

```
$ join -t, -1 5 -2 2 <(join -t, -j 1 file3 file2 | sort -t, -k5,5) file1 | column -s, -t

ARCH  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  1  90  very good  80
ARCH  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  2  70  good       85
ARCH  2  satadisha  binghamton  879-876-54  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  1  90  very good  80
ARCH  2  satadisha  binghamton  879-876-54  Computer Architecture  A  K.Gose  1  2  70  good       85
PLNG  1  pankaj     vestal      986-654-32  Programming Languages  A  P.Yang  1  1  89  very good  85
```

alternatively, you can do the join in `awk` as well, eliminating the while loops.

If you want to add the values in $11.

```
$ join -t, -1 5 -2 2 <(join -t, -j 1 file3 file2 
    | sort -t, -k5,5) file1 | awk -F, '{sum+=$11} END{print sum}'
```

To assign the result to a shell variable

```
$ sum=$(join ... )
```

Comment: this part is working for my while loop code also. I need a way to calculate the sum of  all values in column 11  in the same loop. I mean i dont want to  read the o/p files separately for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have joined the columns to form a TSV (tab-separated values) file or stream, and that columns $k1, $k2, and $k3 (in that file or stream) form the key, and that you want to sum column $s in the join, here is the awk command you can use to form a TSV listing of the keys and sum:

```
awk -F\\t -v k1=$k1 -v k2=$k2 -v k3=$k3 '
  BEGIN{t=OFS="\t"}
  { key=$k1 t $k2 t $k3; sum[key]+=$s }
  END {for (key in sum) {print key, sum[key] } }'
```

(Using awk to process CSV files that might contain commas is asking for trouble, so I've illustrated how to use awk with tabs.)